# PROBLEMAS CON TRIGGERS Y SP EN POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedure, trigger

Me pidieron crear en postgres, un trigger de auditoria que cada vez que se active un procedimiento almacenado, se inserte en otra tabla el nombre de este procedimiento que se llamó.

Comment: y que exactamente debes de guardar? el nombre del procedimiento?

Comment: Si, necesito guardar el nombre de este procedimiento

Comment: Los triggers en PostgreSQL son sobre tablas o sobre algunos eventos específicos, y no incluyen llamadas a procedimientos, lo que puedes hacer es dentro de ese procedimiento tener una línea INSERT... que siempre se ejecute y que inserte en dicha tabla que mencionas